# Why this graph has automorphism group is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order 4?

Tags: graph-theory

My professor say that this graph is a non-separable graph whose automorphism group is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order 4 without telling me why

[image]

I can see this graph has no cut vertex, so it's non-separable. Is can be rotated and flipped symmetrically in manner $R^2 =I=r=r^2$ where $R$ is flipping vertically or horizontally, and $r$ is rotating the graph counter clockwise by 90 degree.

But I still can't see why this graph has automorphism group is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order 4?

Comment: I don't think it can be flipped: that will reverse 2 of the diagonals.

Comment: because if you flip you get another graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Each of automorphism carries a vertex with maximal degree to vertex to maximal degree. Furthermore, there are $4$ vertices with the degree $5$. Hence we have $4$ automorphisms and we can conclude that Aut$(G)\cong \mathbb Z_4$. Note that it is not hard to see that there is an automorphism with order $4$.

Now, assume that $\phi\in Aut(G)$ fixes all vertices with degree $5$. Since each vertex with degree $5$ has a neighborhood  whose degree is $2$, we can conclude that $\phi$ fixes all vertices with degree $2$.

Automorphism $\phi$ fixes all vertices with degree $5$ and $2$ and so ....

Comment: Note that there are only two groups with order $4$($\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_4$).

Comment: @Babak Miraftab: You also need to show that any automorphism that fixes each of the four vertices of degree five is trivial, and even then you only get that the automorphism group is a subgroup of the symmetric group on four points.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil, thanks.

Comment: all vertices of degree 5 also neighbor with vertices of degree 2 as well, so  is it still work if I say $\phi$ fixed all vertices of degree 5 and 2, it's trivially fixed vertices of degree 3? I'm sorry my professor went through this subject very fast and he only explain it by waving his hands around so I'm confused alot.

Comment: each vertex of degree 5 has exactly one nhbd with vertex 2 so if $\phi$ fixes vertices with degree 5, then $\phi$ fixes vertices with degree 2. Now, since each vertex of degree 2 has exactly one nhbd with vertex 3 so if \phi fixes vertices with degree 2, then \phi fixes vertices with degree 3. Thus \phi fixes all vertices. Is it clear?

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: The fact that the automorphisms carry the four degree-5 vertices to each other doesn't itself tell you everything you conclude from it. You could argue that once you know what it does to the degree-5 vertices the rest of the automorphism is determined, but even that will only tell you that Aut(G) is a subgroup of $S_4$, not that it has order 4.

Comment: @HenningMakholm If $\phi$ carries $v_1$ to $v_2$ where $v_i$'s are vertices with degree 5, then $\phi$ should carry $u_1$ to $u_2$ where $u_i$ is nbhd of $v_i$ with degree 2. We can use this fact for determining $\phi$. Is it clear?

Comment: @Babak: I agree that this is true; just pointing out that it's a bit of a large step to hide in a "hence". But I see now that the answer explicitly declares itself to be merely a hint, so perhaps it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

$|Aut(G)|=4 $ because $Aut(G)$ ={$a$, $a^2$, $a^3$,$a^4$ } where is $a$, 90 degree clockwise rotation of  graph. then $Aut(G)$ is cyclic group of order 4. since there 2 group of order 4 then $Aut(G) \cong \mathbb Z_4 $ or $Aut(G) \cong \mathbb Z_2 *\mathbb Z_2 $